# Linux access level permission why it is different for user and UPG

Tags: linux, permissions

I have question related to permission in Linux, which set to user and its user primary group . When we set any permission on UPG and  user is by default is member of UPG group, and here let us  take i set permission RWX for the UPG and RW for the user. Here is the question is why is different permission for user and UPG as the user falls in same group and then whatever permission set to group it will applicable to user because user/owner is member of the UPG. and that is the purpose of the group. Can any body answer my question?